# Unable to connect from on-prem to aws through python paramiko

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, paramiko

Few days back below code is working fine but today starts facing below error. After generating a new key also facing the below error. Can some please suggest.

```
on-prem to on-prem - Connection successfull
on-prem to aws - facing below error
```

**code**

```
import paramiko
import os
ssh_remote =paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_remote.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
privatekeyfile = os.path.expanduser('/home/test/.ssh/id_rsa')
mykey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(privatekeyfile, password='test1234')
ssh_remote.connect('10.10.10.10', username = 'test', pkey = mykey)
hostin, hostout, hosterr = ssh_remote.exec_command("hostname")
source = hostout.read().decode().splitlines()
error = hosterr.read().decode().splitlines()
print 'source = ',source
print 'error = ',error
```

**Error**

```
source =  []
error =  [u'WARNING: Your password has expired.', u'Password change required but no TTY available.']
```

**Version**

```
Python version - 2.7.15
Paramiko version - 2.4.1
OpenSSh version - OpenSSH_5.3p1
```

**Command used to generate key**

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

**Tried to connect manually**

```
ssh test@10.10.10.10
Enter passphrase for key '/home/test/.ssh/id_rsa':
You are required to change your password immediately
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Changing password for user test.
Changing password for test
(current) password:
Enter new password:
Confirm new password:
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
Connection to 10.10.10.10 closed.
```

Comment: So what do you get if you do `ssh test@10.10.10.10 hostname`?

Comment: @Martin Prikryl: It prompt for password change and ended with error.

Comment: OK, so you do not have a programming question. Contact your server administrator.